# SQL Server - Procedure to merge tables ending on word into one table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

It's the first time that I am working with SQL Server, and I need some help. I've to write a stored procedure (with an empty table as input parameter, or maybe a string containing the name is better (?)) that:

- Identifies all tables on the database ending with the name of an input table. E.g. when the input table is called 'test', tables with names like 'table1_test', 'table2_test', ... should be selected.
- merges those tables into the input table (which is empty).

Assumption: tables ending with 'test' have the same structure.

I can identify the tables by using the `like` operator on the `information_schema.tables` table. Then, a table with one column containing all the selected table names is returned. At this point, I'm stuck.

Does somebody know what to do? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** the code I currently have for identifying which tables to insert

```
DECLARE @TARGET VARCHAR(255)
SET @TARGET = 'TEST'
BEGIN
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM sfdc_replica.information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', @TARGET);
END;
```

Comment: Use string concatenation to generate a dynamic insert statement stored in a variable, and then execute the statement.

Comment: If you want more information, I would suggest posting your code.

Comment: `MERGE` requires a field to join on, so unless they are all using the same field name to join, you will have to script each one individually

Comment: You need to first of all find the structure of the tables to build up the new one. I would look in sys.tables, sys.columns and sys.objects with the input table name to build the new table from. Then from here a simple insert into Select would copy the data across. The problem here is that you'll likely encounter duplicated data when copying from the other tables. Hope that gives you a starting point.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. The structure of all tables is the same, and ducplicated data is not an issue. The problem is to write the statement to (1) create the target table and (2) insert the tables into this target table.